# Duplicate Records In Infinite Scroll When Sorting by Random

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a web page with infinite scroll. I'm feeding this scroll with random records (I'm using `order by newid()` for that). There is ajax call which appends page with new random data when scroll reaches the end. Obviously I'm getting duplicate records with this approach. 
Here is my question: is there any way to avoid duplicate records? Should I store somewhere records that already have been loaded to the page and exclude them from the selection? Or should I select huge recordset with random records, keep it in memory, and then feed the page with chunks of this recordset? What is the right way to do random infinite scroll? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

code as requested:

Data provider:

```
res = data.OrderBy(l => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(numberOfRecords);
```

Client:

```
$.get("/Start/Index/", function (data) {
                if (data != '') {                        
                    isLoading = false;
                    $("#tiles").append(data);});
```

Server:

```
model.PageData = _dataProvider.GetOnePage(recordsPerPage);
return PartialView("_MyView", model.PageData);
```

Comment: For a question of this nature - and most all questions on SO - it's much better to _post your code_, to help us get you an answer.

Comment: Please post your sql/c#/client code

Comment: I posted the code as you guys requested, but my approach is wrong by definition. The question is: How would you do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, using newid is not fast for large tables - SqlServer has to assign a random value to each row in the table before it can order.  This MSDN article has has a small discussion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx

To get the "same random results" each time you run your query, you would either need to compute and store the order, or make it predicable based on a seed that you store.

You might try something like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

A property of the  BINARY_CHECKSUM function is that every time that it is used on a row that has not been modified, it returns the same checksum number. Thus, when it is used by itself, subsequent runs of the query return the same "random" set of rows.  Usually this is not desirable, but for your purposes it may be. To make it more random for different users, you could multiple BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) by RAND(?) and pass in a seed that you've stored for that user session.  You also might want to restrict the columns used in BINARY_CHECKSUM to something predictable that doesn't change, like ID and a created_at timestamp and add a where id > .

Putting it all together, the query might look something like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE id > ? AND (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND(?)) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

And you pass in two parameters: the max id when you first displayed the infinite scroll and the seed you generated at that time.

Unfortunately, I couldn't try this out - let me know if it works.

Comment: it's very interesting approach, but there is one issue: this random selection is not quite random. Here is the example of 20 selected records:
272
284
324
352
413
433
23978
24068
24078
24117
24251
24269
24308
24314
24371
24395
24448
24673
24741
24744 
I think it's very promising, but require some tuning...

Comment: Depending on how many rows you have, you maybe could just order by RAND(?) and pass the same seed in on each query from the same infinite scroll session.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of research I figured out that there is no easy way to do random infinite scroll without duplicate records. I decided what if I cannot do random scroll I have to do scroll that just looks like random, but actually is not. So ended up with this solution:

```
data = data.OrderByDescending(link => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(link.link_timestamp)).OrderBy(l => l.link_randomid).Skip(skip).Take(numberOfRecords);
```

where link_randomid is unique random id that generated on record insert.
Hope this will save some time for somebody.